# Minimum length of string that can crash some application

Tags: c, security

We have a weekly test on computer system vulnerability which has the following question:

> The below function is part of a program that is running on a 32-bit x86 system; the compiler does not change the order of variables on the stack.

```
void function(char *input) {
    int i = 1;
    char buffer[8];
    int j = 2;
    strcpy(buffer,input);
    printf("%x %x %s\n",i,j,buffer);

}
```

> What is the minimum length of a string passed to the function through the input parameter that can crash the application?
>
> a)10 b)11 c)12 d)13

I wrote a `main` function to invoke the `void function(...` and compiled the program using `gcc -m32 test.c -o test` because I am on 64 bit computer. Below is the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    function(argv[1]);
    return 1;
}
```

and tested with inputs:

```
~/Dir:./test 1234567
1 2 1234567
~/Dir:./test 12345678
1 2 12345678
~/Dir:./test 123456789
1 2 123456789
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

As soon as I enter `123456789` as argument, stack smashing is detected, so the answer to this question should be `9` but there is no option to select `9`. What should be the correct answer to the above problem? How can I know the minimum length of string that can crash the above application?

Comment: I would have expected some weird behavior at 8 characters already, to be fair.

Comment: Its developer responsibility to make sure `buffer` has enough memory space to store `input` into it else it cause _buffer overflow_ which in turns cause undefined behaviour. use a pattern such as that it allows only `7` character to copy into `input`.

Comment: My point being, at 8 characters you're already invoking undefined behavior, so the question and those possible answers don't make much sense to begin with. Anyway, have you tried decompiling your executable and check how it handles those arguments? Also, I would add `-O0` to the compiler invocation to eliminate any kind of optimization.

Comment: @Achal It's a question, I am not the one who wrote `void function(..`, I only wrote the main function and tested the program.

Comment: "*... minimum length of string that can crash the above application?*" >7. Whether it *will* crash depends on the moon.

Comment: @alk Can you please explain it why or just refer to some documentation that explains it?

Comment: @roundAbout the point of undefined behavior is that it is undefined. You can't find documentation for that. At most, you can find documentation on the man page for `strcpy` (in the BUGS section) that tells you about overflows.

Comment: The buffer is 8 bytes. In C a string needs 1 additional byte to store the `0`-terminator. So the maximal string length to store in 8 bytes is 8 bytes minus 1 byte = 7 bytes. Additional bytes would be written out of `buffer`'s bounds. Writing out of an array's bounds in C invokes the infamous Undefined Behaviour, anything can happen from then on.

Comment: `"%x"` associated with an `int` value invokes UB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting “Stack smashing detected” with 9 characters because your compiler does reorder variables on the stack. GCC does, even at `-O0`. To prevent this, put the variables in a struct.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct variables {
    int i;
    char buffer[8];
    int j;
};
void function(char *input) {
    struct variables s;
    s.i = 1;
    s.j = 2;
    strcpy(s.buffer, input);
    printf("%x %x %s\n", s.i, s.j, s.buffer);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    function(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile this with optimizations turned off, otherwise the compiler is very likely to optimize `s` itself away.

```
$ ./a.out 1234567                    
1 2 1234567
$ ./a.out 12345678
1 0 12345678
$ ./a.out 123456789
1 39 123456789
$ ./a.out 1234567890
1 3039 1234567890
$ ./a.out 1234567890a
1 613039 1234567890a
$ ./a.out 1234567890ab
1 62613039 1234567890ab
$ ./a.out 1234567890abc
1 62613039 1234567890abc
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
[2]    6086 abort (core dumped)  ./a.out 1234567890abc
```

Now you can see what's going on. With up to 7 characters, plus the null terminator, the string fits in the 8-byte buffer. With 8 characters, the string starts overflowing onto the next thing in memory, which is `j`. On a 32-bit little-endian machine, the bytes that make up `j` have the values {0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}. With 8 to 11 characters, the string progressively takes over `j`.

At 12 characters, the null terminator overwrites whatever is in memory after `s`. In my test, this byte in memory happened to have the value 0, so nothing worse happened than the overwrite of `j`. At 13 characters, the last character of the string `c` overwrites that byte, which is detected by the stack protection because that byte is in fact part of the stack canary.

In my build, the number of characters it takes to cause crash is 13. However, this is because there happens to be a null byte after `j`. Given the assumptions of the exercise, the number of characters it takes to *possibly* crash the application is **12**. At this point, the `strcpy` call writes past the local storage of the function, and this could be an unmapped address.

For visual reference, this is the content of the memory before the `strcpy` call:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 01 | 00 | 00 | 00 | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | ?? | 02 | 00 | 00 | 00 | 00 | ?? |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
 ^-i                 ^-buffer                                ^-j                 ^-stack canary
```

If I compile with `gcc -O0 -fno-stack-protector`, it takes 21 bytes to actually cause a crash on my platform, presumably because that's what it takes to overwrite the return address. Exercise (I haven't looked and I don't know how hard it is): with a debugger and with the help of the assembly code and some x86 ABI documentation, find out what's there (frame pointer? alignment gap?).

Answer (score 1):

This question is working under the assumption that the compiler isn't reordering the variables on the stack and that it isn't exploiting undefined behavior to perform certain optimizations, but your test program is doing just that.  It is most likely putting the array at the highest address on the stack so that it takes less characters to cause a crash.

Under the constraints of the question, the answer would be 12 provided an `int` is 4 bytes.  Characters 9 - 12 would be written to the bytes of one of the `int` variables, and the terminating null byte for the string would be written one byte past that, potentially into the function's return address.